# Connecting to multiple cores at runtime

Tags: solrnet

Is there a way to define a connection to a new Solr core on the fly, based on dynamic data?

We have a scenario where our Solr installation has multiple Cores/Indexes for the same type of document, separated by date (so a given week's documents will be on Index 1, the previous week's on Index 2, etc).

So when I receive my query, I check to see the required date range, and based on it, I want to query a specific core. I don't know in advance, at startup, which cores I will have, since new ones can be created dynamically during runtime.

Using the built-in ServiceLocation provider, there's no way to link two different Cores to the same document class. But even if I use a different DI container (currently Autofac in my case), I still need to specify all Core URLs in advance, during component registration.

Is there a way to bypass it except for always creating a new Autofac Container, generating the ISolrOperation<> class from it, and releasing it until the next time I need to connect to a core?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/solrnet/N0tj_ILL1Gw/4D7Rvr7jAgAJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mauricio Scheffer (developer of Solr.Net)'s [comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/solrnet/N0tj_ILL1Gw/4D7Rvr7jAgAJ) confirmed that there's no built-in support for connecting to different index URLs on the fly. So instead of instantiating the internal objects myself, I used a hack on top of my existing Autofac based DI container:

```
public ISolrOperations<TDocument> ConnectToIndex<TDocument>(string indexUrl)
{
    // Create a new AutoFac container environment.
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder(); 

    // Autofac-for-Solr.Net config element.
    var cores = new SolrServers 
    {
        new SolrServerElement 
        {
            Id = indexUrl,
            DocumentType = typeof (TDocument).AssemblyQualifiedName,
            Url = indexUrl,
        }
    };

    // Create the Autofac container.
    builder.RegisterModule(new SolrNetModule(cores));
    var container = builder.Build();

    // Resolve the SolrNet object for the URL.     
    return container.Resolve<ISolrOperations<TDocument>>();
}
```